# Show and Hide functions in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a code in html -3 Div's which come after radio buttons.
I want that a click on each button will show the code that's in the that button's div, and will hide both of the other div's.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id="A" method="get" action="form.php"> <fieldset>
             <legend> A </legend>

                <div id="Headline">Headline: </div>
                <div><input type="radio" name="B" value="B" onclick="functionb('b')">  <img class="photos" src="b.gif" alt="b"><br><div id="b>Show B</div>
                    <input type="radio" name="C" value="C" onclick="functionc('c')"><img class="photos" src="c.gif" alt="c"><br><div id="c">Show C</div>
                    <input type="radio" name="d" value="d" onclick="functiond('d')"><img class="photos" src="d.gif" alt="d"></div><br><div id="d">Show D</div>

             </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wrote the next code in the JS file (I need to put all the scripts in a different file that the html one) just for the first button:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#b").click(function(){
            $("#b").show();
            $("#c").hide();
            $("#d").hide();
           });
       });
```

and it doesn't do the action needed when pressing the first button...
Be glad to get any help - thank you!!

Comment: can you add some more details.?

Comment: That JS code doesn't make sense; you don't have anything with id `v` or `i` in the HTML above.

Comment: where did you get these ids. these are not used in your html.

Comment: Not to mention clicking on 'v' will show 'v', why would you show something After it is clicked, doesn't it have to be shown to click on it?

Comment: Well to begin with your inputs need to have end tags <input ... />, same with images what does #v mean there is no element in your mark up with id="v", also please don't use onclick = ".." it is bad practice with separation of concerns

Comment: You're right, I changed the HTML to ABC so it won't be full of confusing information...
it  needs to look like this:

$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#a").click(function(){
            $("#a").show();
            $("#b").hide();
            $("#c").hide();
           });
       });

Comment: how can you click an element which is hidden? @Bramat

Comment: I whant to hide what's in the div after the button - when I press on one of the other buttons...

Comment: I edited it now - hope it's clearer...
I need for all three buttons to be visible at all time - and by clicking the first button (id="b")' only the content of b will be visible, and c and d won't
@Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of things that you need to address . . .

First off, you mention that you are clicking a radio button and that it should show the related div, and hide the others.  Then you show this section of code (comments added by me):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#v").click(function() {  // This is the button click
        $("#v").show();         // This shows the related div
        $("#a").hide();         // This hides "other div" number 1
        $("#i").hide();         // This hides "other div" number 2
    });
});
```

Problem is, you are referencing the radio button with the `id` attribute of the target `<div>` element (`$("v")`). You need to reference the radio button another way, for example `$("input[name='v']")` (since the names should be unique in the form).  That selects the input with the `name` attribute that is equal to "v".

In the end, though, you should probably make the function generic, so that you don't have to reference each radio button specifically.  You could do this by grabbing all of the radio buttons in the form, for example . . . like this:

```
$("#A").find("input[type='radio']")
```

That would get all of the radio button inputs in the "A" form.  Then you can attach a click function to each of them (see more below).

Secondly, I'd recommend giving all of the divs a common a common class.  That way, you can tie the `.hide()` reference to a common class, rather than individual `id` attributes.  Then you can come back and show the specific `<div>` after all of them have been hidden first.

Using the two suggestions above (and removing some of your other code, just to simplify my answer . . . you can add it back in, in  your final code   :)   ), here is an example of what might work for you:

**HTML**

```
<form id="a" method="get" action="form.php">
    <input type="radio" name="b" value="b">
    <img class="photos" src="b.gif" alt="b"><br>
    <div id="b" class="subForm">Show B</div>

    <input type="radio" name="c" value="c">
    <img class="photos" src="c.gif" alt="c"><br>
    <div id="c" class="subForm">Show C</div>

    <input type="radio" name="d" value="d">
    <img class="photos" src="d.gif" alt="d"></div><br>
    <div id="d" class="subForm">Show D</div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").find("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        $(".subForm").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).show();
    });
});
```

With this approach, you gather all of the radio buttons in the form and attach a generic "click" function to them.  The function will hide all of the divs (now marked with a common "subForm" class), and then will show the div that has the `id` attribute that matches the `name` attribute of the radio button that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Set a common class in your "button display divs"

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="b" value="B"><img class="photos" src="b.gif" alt="b"><br /><div id="b" class="ButtonDisplayDiv">Show B</div>
  <input type="radio" name="c" value="C"><img class="photos" src="c.gif" alt="c"><br /><div id="c" class="ButtonDisplayDiv">Show C</div>
  <input type="radio" name="d" value="D"><img class="photos" src="d.gif" alt="d"><br /><div id="d" class="ButtonDisplayDiv">Show D</div>
</div>
```

Then for your radio button event handler

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
   $('.ButtonDisplayDiv').hide(); //hide all the ButtonDisplayDiv Class Elements
   $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).show;  //show the associated selected div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try accessing element by name attribute:

```
$('input[name=B]').click(function(){// your action here});
```

or if you need to access by id, then add id attribute:

```
<input type="radio" id="B" name="B" value="B" onclick="functionb('b')"><img class="photos" src="b.gif" alt="b"><br /><div id="b" class="ButtonDisplayDiv">Show B</div>
```